# Both php4 and php5 running on one system

Tags: php, php4

I'm having a problem with my customer's host.
The host has configured the server in a way that php4 and php5 co-exist.
If you want to use php4, you just have to use a .php extension for your files.
If you want to use php5, you have to use a .php5 extension.

The problem with this configuration is that I'm using a system which has a codebase of 5000+ files all having a .php extension, but using native features of php5.

Is there a way to avoid having to rename every file to a .php5 extension and having to rewrite a small part of the codebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on your host. You can override the handler for file types with this directive put in an `.htaccess` file, as long as your host hasn't disallowed it:

```
AddHandler php5-script .php
```